# shiny, table slicing, textfield

Tags: r, shiny, dt

What I need help implementing is:
I have a table in shiny, and I would like to slice the table according to the user input.
For example the user types 1, 4-6, and then they would see only the first and 4th-6th column.
I thought of implementing it with a textfield, but first of all it does not work, second it is dangerous from a security point of view to allow users to type also characters, since it should only be numeric anyway.

Another solution that comes into my mind is to have several NumericInputs/ Numeric Range Input, but I thought maybe knows of a bit more elegant solution? (some textfield where only numeric values would be allowed. where the user could type ranges as well as single numeric values)

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("slice", "Slicing", "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',

        tabPanel("mtcars", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  

  
  output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    print(input$slice)
    xm <- as.numeric(input$slice)
    if (!is.na(xm)){
    DT::datatable(mtcars[,xm], options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
    }
    else {
      DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE)) 
    }
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `pickerInput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "mtcars DataTable",
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("columns", "Select columns", choices = seq_along(mtcars), 
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(input$columns)) {
      DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE)) 
    } else {
      selected_columns <- as.numeric(input$columns) # convert character to numeric
      DT::datatable(mtcars[, selected_columns, drop = FALSE], options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]